# Ошибка "Activity OfficeChecker has leaked window DecorView that was originally added here"

Tags: android, java

Что это за ошибка и из-за чего она возникает? Ни один из этих классов не находится в моем приложении (типа `com.olivephone.edit.update.OfficeChecker`).

```
ERROR/WindowManager(16794): Activity com.olivephone.edit.update.OfficeChecker has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@408bc380 that was originally added here
        android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.olivephone.edit.update.OfficeChecker has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@408bc380 that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:288)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:249)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:532)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:269)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:115)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:103)
        at com.olivephone.edit.update.OfficeChecker.onCreate(OfficeChecker.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Каждое окно имеет своего родителя, если закрыть родителя перед тем как закрыть потомка возникает ошибка: window leak - утечка окна. Обычно это возникает когда из активити создается диалог, затем закрывается активити, а диалог остается висеть (в реальности оконная система все равно его закрывает).

Соответственно, в ошибке указывается место где был добавлен диалог, чтобы разработчик мог правильно обработать это место.

Ошибка несмертельная, но неприятная.